# Get the a part of content from NSString

Tags: html, objective-c, nsstring

I want to ask something about the NSString in objective C. I use the following code to retrieve some of the HTML content.

```
NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;  
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString *data = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

In the `data`, it contains lot of HTML code e.g.

```
<!DOCTY... >
...
// retrieve the content from <form> to </form>
<form method="post" action="...">
    <input type="..." name="name_1" value="value_1" />
    <input type="..." name="name_2" value="value_2" />
</form>
...    
</html>
```

I want to get the content of the name_1, value_1, name_2 and value_2 to and NSString, just like

```
NSString A = "name_1"

NSString B = "value_1"

NSString C = "name_2"

NSString D = "value_2"
```

Does the NSString provide this kind of search or method to retrieve the string? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

NSString can and does but it would be very messy.

If you are intent on parsing the NSString take a look a [NSScanner](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html), otherwise check out parsing using the [NSXMLDocument](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

--Frank